# ¿Como insertar un select en una tabla (Datatables)?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

Uso `datatables` para listar datos traidos de una DB pero necesito que en una columna de las filas insertar un select (lista desplegable) intente de esta manera pero no funciono..

```
var users = $('#users').DataTable(
    {});
    $.ajax({
            url: 'users',
            type: 'POST'
        })
        .done(function(answer) {
            var result= $.parseJSON(answer);    

            for (var i = result.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
            {
        .row.add([
                                result[i].id,
                                result[i].nombre,
                                result[i].apellido,
                               '<select><option>-- Seleccione --</option></selec>',
                                '<a class="btn-floating btn-small waves-effect waves-light red hoverable"><i class="material-icons">content_paste</i></a>'
                            ])
                        .draw()
                   .node();
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        });
```

**¿Como podria arreglarlo?**

Comment: Y por que no funcionó. Salió algo? No salio nada? dio error?

Comment: no me muestra errores ni nada extraño, simplemente no aparecio en la vista

Comment: Y no tienes algun tipo de log o print que te diga qué está haciendo?

Comment: si por fuera del for inserto ('<select><option>--seleccione--<option></select>',) en una variable y hago un cosnole.log(me lo imprimi tal cual)

Comment: Si tu código tal cual como esta, te hace falta una comilla de cierre antes de la ultima coma.

Comment: tampoco funciona

Comment: Pon el ejemplo completo y déjanos compilarlo con datos dummies, por favor.

Comment: listo ya lo he puesto completo

Comment: `.row.add([` Dónde está el objeto que hace referencia a la tabla?

Comment: @ user2930137 listo

Comment: ¿Se solucionó?, ¿era eso?

Comment: ese es el objeto, no se ha solucionado nada

Comment: Hombre pues añádelo al código que te cité.
`users.row.add([`

Comment: @user2930137 gracias por tu colaboración pero creo que no has manejado datatables, de pronto el problema es algo simple que no he podido encontrar pero la pregunta es..si me funciona un botón como no me va a funcionar un select...gracias por tu interés sobre este problema...Saludos

Comment: Solo hazlo. Escribe `users.row.add`

Comment: no me funciono...

Answer (score 1):

Amigo con este codigo validas que el campo que creaste en el data table y insertas los valores en el dropdown o en su defecto en el select.

```js
if($(column.footer()).hasClass('groupprices')){
      var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
        .on( 'change', function () {
         var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
         //alert($(this).val());
         column.search(val,  false, false, true).draw();
        });

      column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
       select.append('<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>');
      });
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar "render" en la definición de tu columna:

En las definiciones de tus columnas:

```
 "columns": [
    { "data"   : "id" },
    { "data"   : "nombre" },
    { "data"   : "apellido"},
    { "data"   : "select",
      "render" : function ( data, type, row ) {
                       return '<select><option>-- Seleccione --</option></selec>';
                 }
    }
  ]
```

el parámetro "data" hace referencia al valor del dato de esa celda (en este caso "select") mientras que "row" es un objeto con el cual puedes acceder a cualquier otra propiedad del objeto que traes para insertar la fila: row.id, row.nombre,...

Answer (score 0):

Datatables no va a saber mágicamente a qué objetos estás intentando agregar una fila. Debes especificarlo.

```
   var users = $('#users').DataTable({});

    users.row.add( [ 100, 'Nombre', 'Apellido', '<select><option>Uno</option></select>', 'El link' ] )
    .draw()
    .node();
```

Y asegúrate que haga match el número de columnas que tienes actualmente al número de columnas que estás creando en row.add.

Comment: :/ eso ya lo he realizado metiendo el users en una variable, ejemplo var table = users.row.add([..]) por que el esta tomando la variable asignada por el datatables...yo creo que el problema principalmente es de la inserción html dentro del arreglo...